# how to load the external html in a div

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="feeds"></div>
<script>
$("#feeds").load("test2.html");
</script>
```

This is my code, please tell me what am I doing wrong

regards
San

Comment: Does test2.html exist? Make sure you are not getting a 404 when you try to load test2.html. Your syntax looks correct otherwise except you also want to wait until the DOM has loaded first.

Comment: first make sure you using a jquery lib.  and check you `js error console` and paste here what error you got ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add some

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#feeds").load("test2.html");
})
```